# React useEffect and Axios fetching object array results and displaying on frontend

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to use React's useEffect() to GET data with Axios from the Express backend server. I'm able to console.log the response on the frontend (screenshot included). However I'm not able to map the array and display the items on the frontend.

I want the data from the results array to display on the frontend cards and create a list of cards when mapping thought the array.

React Frontend:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  //Test: onClick handler to get the data from the server backend
  //and display the response on the frontend(console window).
  // const getHealthData = async () => {
  //         axios.get("/health")
  //         .then(res => {
  //           console.log(res.data.results) //success
  //         }).catch(err => {
  //           console.log(err);
  //         })
  //       }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const fetchResults = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get("/health"); //http://localhost/3000/health
          setResults(response.data.results);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      fetchResults();

    }, 60000); //1 minute timeout
  }, [results]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        //Testing API call with onClick
        {/* <button onClick={getHealthData}>Get Health Data</button> */}

        // I want to map through the results data and return the object key values into the card.

       {results.map((result, index) => ( 
        
        <div key={index} className="card">
          <h2 className="card-title">Health</h2>
          <p className="card-text">Checker: {result.checker}</p>
          <p className="card-text">Output: {result.output}</p>
          <p className="card-text">Passed: {result.passed}</p>
          <p className="card-text">Timestamp: {result.timestamp}</p>
          <p className="card-text">Expires: {result.expires}</p>
        </div>
      ))};
      </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Express backend server(proxy):

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors'); 
require('dotenv').config();
const PORT = 5000;

app.use(cors({}))

app.get(':endpoint([\\/\\w\\.-]*)', function(req, res){ 

    let endpoint = process.env.LOCALHOST_URL + req.params.endpoint;

    axios.get(endpoint).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        res.json(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
        res.json(error.message)
    })
});


app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server started on 'http://localhost:5000'")
})
```

JSON REST Api Sample:

```js
{
  hostname: '23c10882746a',
  status: 'success',
  timestamp: 1660297130.9966166,
  results: [
    {
      checker: 'postgres_available',
      output: 'Postgres OK',
      passed: true,
      timestamp: 1660297113.0233154,
      expires: 1660297140.0233154
    },
    {
      checker: 'message_queue_available',
      output: 'Message Queue OK',
      passed: true,
      timestamp: 1660297113.0477347,
      expires: 1660297140.0477347
    },
    {
      checker: 'disk_space_enough',
      output: '232 GB Free out of 314 GB Total. 73.9% remaining',
      passed: true,
      timestamp: 1660297113.0478468,
      expires: 1660297140.0478468
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also included a screenshot of the data in the browser.

[Chrome Browser Network Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfJjv.png)

Comment: The `results` variable doesn't exist, shouldn't it be `health`?

Comment: I've replaced health with results.

Comment: When you say you're able to console log the response, where did you console.log ?

Comment: console.log(res.data.results)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `map()` call. Try replacing `results` with `result`:

```
<div key={index} className="card">
  <h2 className="card-title">Health</h2>
  <p className="card-text">Checker: {result.checker}</p>
  <p className="card-text">Output: {result.output}</p>
  <p className="card-text">Passed: {result.passed}</p>
  <p className="card-text">Timestamp: {result.timestamp}</p>
  <p className="card-text">Expires: {result.expires}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've update the code with the correct spelling and variables. But still not able to map the data. 

```<p className="card-text">Checker: {result.checker}</p>
```

result.checker is underlined in red: "Property 'checker' does not exist on type 'never'. ts(2339)"

Comment: Please share the error message you get. @Dylan

Comment: Error message: "Property 'checker' does not exist on type 'never'. ts(2339)"

Comment: `results.map((result: any, index) =>` add type `any` here ... not the best solution but for now this should fix it

Comment: So that seems to have fixed the error but the cards are not displaying on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

`results` variable does not exists, your data is stored inside `health` state. And you also have typo inside your map function, use `result` instead.

```
health.map(result, index...)
```

Comment: I've made updates to the code. Please have a look above at the comments. Thank you